# How to visualize an grouped and aggregated pandas dataframe with seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, seaborn, aggregation

I am surprised that I have to ask this question. I expect the solution to be easy.

**Situation:**

I have some pandas.DataFrame `df`. I do groups and aggregation on it, like so:

```
df.groupby(
    ['colA','colB']
).agg(
    {
    'colC': "count"
    }
)
```

So we are grouping by `colA` and `colB` and doing an aggregation (counting the number of occurrences in this case) on `colC`.

The **result** will look something like this (first table):

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| colA       | colB       | colC       |
+============+============+============+
| 1          | A          | 42         |
+------------+------------+------------+
|            | B          | 43         |
+------------+------------+------------+
|            |            | 44         |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

I now want to visualize this table with seaborn. Logically, this should work because what the first table represents is

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| colA       | colB       | colC       |
+============+============+============+
| 1          | A          | 42         |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 1          | B          | 43         |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 1          | B          | 44         |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

, which can easily be represented (second table). My code for visualization looks like this:

```
g = sns.catplot(x="colA", y="colC", hue="colC") # some more params
```

The error that I get is `Could not interpret input 'colA'`. I assume that is, because `colA` and `colB` are viewed as a key, since I used them in the groupby clause. I would guess that I would have to somehow convert the dataframe table (first table) to a "normal" dataframe (second table). Is this correct? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: You can always just `reset` the index: `sns.catplot(x="colA", y="colB", hue="colC", data=df.reset_index())`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Could you post that as an answer @ALollz